# REST API Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I have a code igniter controller ," TEST " . and I want to access this controller in REST API.

When I include this controler file using " include_once(APPPATH.'/controllers/test.php'); " , everything works fine.

But Is this the only way to access the controller inside REST API? or is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like a rather unlogical approach.

Have a look at [creating own libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html). The REST API should be easy to implement through there and it's much more logical.

Comment: >class MY_Controler extends CI_Controller{
> public function __construct() {
>  parent::__construct();
>  
> }
> public function rosters($output_format){
>  //here i have code which does xml parsing of a file and generate an array and  get render view file..
>
>  //I have to use the same function but with a parameter passed i have to take generated aray and json  encode it and return ..no rendering of the view file.
>  
> }
>
> }